# Listen to user input only, not changes done with code in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener, user-input, event-listener

I'm using a Polymer paper-slider element, and have tried to use the value-change event listener, which fires a the event listener function whenever a value changes associated with that slider. Unfortunately, if I change the value of the slider programmatically, it also fires the event, which I do not want to happen.

I've also tried the function below, but if my mouse cursor drags beyond the bounds of the slider element, the function will not fire even though I can see the change has taken place with the slider.

```
$(lineWidthEl).on("mouseup paste keyup", function() {
    console.log('yes');
});
```

Similarly, if I use the jQuery "change" event, it fires anytime the value changes programmatically.

The code I use to change an element value is just simple jQuery:

```
$('#myEl').val(3);
```

Comment: Roland - I updated the code.

Comment: Unfortunately that change event doesn't work properly with paper-slider. The slider would have to be clicked after the mouse button was released to get the correct value. The only work around I think I can do related to that is use setTimeOut for 10 milliseconds, but seems annoying.

Comment: You're correct, "change" doesn't fire, but it also doesn't behave properly, because it's unable to get the value of the element that has just changed immediately, which is why I now have to wrap getting that value in a 1 ms setTimeOut function. Polymer's "value-change" event listener works properly, except that programmatically changing the slider also fires the event.

Comment: Maybe, you can reconsider your data model. e.g. having a property bound to your paper-slide, and another property to be changed programmatically. And, synchronize their values as you wish, with the help of an observer on the first property.